# Cheapest way to transfer USD from GB to Israel

Tags: uk, money, israel, exchange

I have a friend who owes me ~600 GB pounds.

I have asked him to pay me in USD.

What is the cheapest way to transfer the money from the UK to Israel?

1) I have checked Paypal - 3.5% commissin for transfering to Paypal. Then 2% for exchanging to NIS. + commission for withdrawing and then enother (external) commission to change back to USD.

2) I have thought about sending cash in registered mail. But I'm afraid someone will scan it and steal it. Is it lligal anhow to send money (even in small amounts, say 150 USD) in registered mail?

3) We don't have any relative who travels between these two countries.

4) WU - too expensive (5% for deposite)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about personal money, ask it in [Personal Finance & Money.SE](http://money.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an online exchange like xe.com. The setup takes a while but it's one of the best rates you can get. It is mainly made for people that need to transfer a large amount of money on a regular basis so it might be overkill for you.

Comment: any one-time online money transfer?

Comment: does this include sending money or just exchanging it?